# getting both HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL and HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: jsp, servlets

Learning some Java Web development here and trying to start my first servlet.  But I am getting this error:  `HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`

`description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL).`

I am using the 'get' method in my html form and, as you can see I have the doget method implemented.  But I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  Could it have something to do with my `web.xml`?

I tried using the POST method by changing the html method to 'post' and by using the doPost method but I get the equivalent error for it, too.  I only did this to test and I don't want to use post.

web.xml:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>AppleFox</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.AppleFox.web.ProcessQuery</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>AppleFox</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/ProcessQuery.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servlet code:

```
package com.AppleFox.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ProcessQuery
 */
public class ProcessQuery<HttpServletRequest> extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String query = ((ServletRequest) request).getParameter("query");

        out.println("Sorry we could find any results for " + query + ".");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm also using the 'get' method in my html form.  Don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the following line and rearrange the imports and everything should work fine:

Change:

```
public class ProcessQuery<HttpServletRequest> extends HttpServlet {
```

to

```
public class ProcessQuery extends HttpServlet {
```

change the imports to:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested to use both doget and dopost methods you can put the action java code in proccessRequest(request,response)
and call it in both of dopost and doget method
like this

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Birhan
 */
@WebServlet(name = "servlet", urlPatterns = {"/servlet"})
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet servlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet servlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```